# Can we use :podspec link with dependencies in a podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, cocoapods

I want to add a dependency to a local podspec with a remote one?
My podspec looks like below:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'AEonSecurity'
  s.version = '0.1.0'
  s.summary = 'add description here'
  s.source_files = 'ios-aeon-security/AEonSecurity/**/*.{h,m}'
      s.dependency 'CernCoreLibrary',                 :podspec => 'http://github.cerner.com/ion/ios-cern-core-library/blob/1.11.0/CernCoreLibrary.podspec'
      s.dependency 'GTMLibrary',                      :git => 'git://github.cerner.com/ion/ios-gtm-library.git'
      s.dependency 'CommonUnitTestUtilLibrary',       :git => 'git://github.cerner.com/ion/ios-common-unittest-util.git'
end
```

Apparently it does not like the :podspec to link to the remote podspec? Does cocopods version 0.28.0 not support this anymore?

The error I am getting is:

```
[!] Invalid `AEonSecurity.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
s.source_files = 'ios-aeon-security/AEonSecurity/**/*.{h,m}'
 >        s.dependency 'CernCoreLibrary', :podspec => 'http://github.cerner.com/ion/ios-cern-core-library/blob/1.11.0/CernCoreLibrary.podspec'
 #        s.dependency 'GTMLibrary', :git => 'git://github.cerner.com/ion/ios-gtm-library.git'
```